# Jekyll how to display an image in a post

Tags: image, jekyll

I am trying to follow the Jekyll docs and am stuck on how to display an image

```
---
layout: post
title:  "My first post!"
date:   2016-10-20 16:17:57 +0200
categories: jekyll update
regenerate: true
---

This is in the `_posts` directory.
It can be edited then rebuild the site to see the changes.
You can rebuild the site in many different ways, but the most common way is to run `jekyll serve`, which launches a web server and auto-regenerates your site when a file is updated.

![name of the image][{{site.url}}/assets/P6740674.JPG]
```

I feel very silly asking this question as it is so basic but I can not find any answers to my question

Is it possibly a configuration error on my own system. I am using apache2, ruby gems, etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 51):

If you want to use `site.url`, you have to add a `url` variable to your `_config.yml` file. More info in the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/).

But you might not have to use `site.url` at all. Any urls that start with a `/` slash will be relative to the top level of your domain. So you could do this:

```
![image tooltip here](/assets/image.jpg)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Kevin. It led me to the understanding of the problem. In fact I used /assets and this referred to the directory _assets so it could not find the file. When I changed it to a folder /img everything worked

Comment: How to do this when you have all of your images uploaded to the folder *images* on Github?

Comment: @FaCoffee If you have a follow-up question, please post it in its own question post. But my guess would be you just need to add `/images/` to any url you use: `![image tooltip here](/images/assets/image.jpg)`

Comment: How do I make this to be displayed in center of the page in layout `page`

Comment: @KrishnaOza If you have a follow-up question, please post it in its own question post. But my guess would be you'd need to use [CSS](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/html/css) to style your page.

Answer (score 10):

I could see an `images` directory created under `assets` by default. I've placed an image as follows.

`assets/images/myimage.jpg` and add following line in the post.

```
![My image Name](/assets/images/myimage.jpg)
```

Run `bundle exec jekyll serve` and see if there is any error. If you have mentioned mismatching file location, you will see error here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is annoying simple - you have the wrong format for your image link.

It should be `![name](link)`. You have `![name][link]`. Note the difference in the brackets. Everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I spent some 15min on this (jekyll/github blog is my secondary blog). So adding a suggestion here.

Briefly, as Kevin [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198284/668951), add the image file to a path under the root and give path to that file. Make sure that the file/directory is being tracked; not .gitignored.

My assets directory is inside _site directory. But, when I added a new image under that path git status did not show it as newly added-  .gitignore ignored the _site directory. So Kevin's suggestion did not work as is. But as per his suggestion, I reasoned that as docs is my site's root, if I add an images directory there and add the image under that then something like

```
![image description](/images/my_image.png)
```

should work. And it worked this way. Not sure if this is the best way. Sharing here in case you have similar config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to push the image to remote and therefore the image didn't show. Just to keep this in mind as well.